# What is the right approach when I have many classes with same properties, but they differ in methods like Load and Refresh?

Tags: c#

Every instance of classes A, B and more is singleton and I would like to be able to loop over these instances with foreach.

```
abstract class Base 
{ 
    public int Property { get; set; }
    public abstract void Load();
}

class A : Base
{
    public override Load(){do stuff that A needs to decide how to set Property}
}

class B : Base
{
    public override Load(){do stuff that B needs to decide how to set Property}
}
```

Is this alright? How do I create a List of these different objects?

Comment: Maybe an [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/interface) can help you with your problem

Comment: In my opinion, you should create an `interface` with `void Load()` method. Then make Base implements your interface `Base : ILoadable`, and implement your method in both `A` and `B`.

Comment: @OndrejTucny I'd say it's pretty clear what the OP wants to achieve. And if you want to loop over each item, I'd say a common `Interface` implemented by each class would be the way to go. Then create a List of type yourInterface

Comment: @OndrejTucny I would like to be able to loop over List that contains one instance of A, one instace of B, one instance of C and so on to call Load on all of them

Comment: @ČeněkSůva Well, you have a common ancestor. So what problem have you encountered? Go ahead and show the relevant code.

Comment: @OndrejTucny I have not encountered a problem with getting it to work. Iam asking because I want to hear how experienced people approach it.

Comment: Well, you didn´t provide *what* you´ve tried. So how could we know our solution is better or worse than yours? Anyway: if you allready *have* a working solution, you should consider to post this question as review on https://codereview.stackexchange.com. But also there we assume that you provide what you´ve tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you have to get all the types that inherit your `Base`-class using reflection:

```
var types = myAssembly.GetTypes().Where(x => x.BaseType == typeof(Base));
```

Now get the instances of those types. As all your class are singletons there´s only one instance per class. This assumes you have some property that enables accessing that single instance.

```
var instances = types.GetProperty("Instance").GetValue(null);
```

Now put those instances into a list and loop them in order to call your `Load`-method. As you already know all the types derive from `Base` you can safely cast them to that class while looping:

```
foreach(Base instance in instances)
    instance.Load();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to achieve this:

```
List<Base> list = new List<Base>();
list.Add(new A());
list.Add(new B());
foreach (var t in list) 
      t.Load();
```

Comment: Those classes are singletons. You can´t create instances of singletons as their constructor is usually private.

Comment: I just put an example how to use Abstract or Interface in loop with subclases or implimentations. Already he have to think of the other steps to achieve his logic. Also he wrote "Every instance of classes A, B "

Comment: Also, pay notice to the compile-time warning. If the C# compiler said the member A hides the other member B. Do not use the new keyword to make the warning go away. Instead, either remove the "extra" member from the derived class or, if you need both members, choose another name for the new member that does not conflict with the names inherited from the base class. Of course, if you want to specialize the behavior of an inherited member, use virtual on base, and override.